# Motor Speed depends on voltage or number of turns

Tags: electromagnetism

What limit the size of motor speed?
Does the speed of motor depend on the voltage applied or magnetic field strenght or frequency or what?

Comment: Magnetic field and applied voltage both but not frequency.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-is-there-not-an-infinite-regress-in-the-emf-of-a-motor.877978/) discussion will be helpful.

Comment: @Manzoor Shah Khalil , are you talking about a DC motor or an AC motor?

Comment: In an AC induction motor, frequency is very much a factor.

Answer (score 1):

> Motor Speed depends on voltage or number of turns

The electric motor speed depends on both the applied voltage and the number of turns of its coil.

The more turns the motor has the higher the strength of the rotor magnetic field if the current is maintained constant. The problem is that, as you add turns, the electric resistance of the coil increases so you also have to rise the voltage to keep the current same as before.

As the strength of the magnetic field increases also the attraction - repulsion force of the rotor increases and in consequence its speed increases.

[image]
[Source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/416794140491580120/)

Answer (score 0):

There was AC synchronous motors that the rotation of the shaft is synchronized with the frequency of the supply current;